# For Nexus 4, Google Play Dashboard says compatible, Play Store app says not

Tags: android, compatibility, google-play, nexus-4

Google Play Dashboard lists the following products as supported when I type "Nexus" in the search box:

```
.   HTCNexus One– passion
.   GoogleGalaxy Nexus– toro
.   GoogleNexus 4– mako
.   SamsungGalaxy Nexus– maguro
.   GoogleNexus 7– grouper
.   SamsungNexus S– crespo4g
.   Nexus 7
.   SamsungNexus S– crespo
.   SamsungGalaxy Nexus– toroplus
.   GoogleNexus 10– manta
.   GoogleNexus 7
```

So, It is obvious that Google Nexus 4 is supported.

However, I have received a message and screenshot which shows that user's device shows a message like "Your device isn't compatible with this version".

How and why can this happen?

**Update**:

User is using Paranoid ROM on his Nexus 4

Comment: Did the user replace the ROM on their device?

Comment: I am waiting a reply from the user, I'll update the question as soon as it arrives. Would changing the ROM cause this? Is it fixable by my side?

Comment: "Would changing the ROM cause this?" -- anything is possible once you are no longer running a stock ROM and are using a pirated Play Store app. "Is it fixable by my side?" -- I have no idea.